# How redirect with htaccess where Last File Name Matches

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We would like to make a wordpress site redirect where the file location of the url begins with "category" and ends with "/tant" to category/file_names?tant, for example:

`/category/filename/tant`
should redirect to 
`/category/filename?tant`

and

`/category/filename/filename/tant`
should redirect to
`/category/filename/filename?tant`

and

`/category/filename/filename/filename/tant`
should redirect to
`/category/filename/filename/filename?tant`

We've tried this 2 different ways, neither of which appear to work:

```
# first method we tried
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/tant$ /category/$1?tant [B,N,QSA,L]

# the 2nd method we tried
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/tant$ /category/$1?tant [B,N,QSA,L]
```

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: I think RewriteRule ^ - [L] is the matched rule. Try moving "RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/" before.

Comment: I believe that tells apache to not run the rewriete if the file exists.  We just tried the rewrite rule without the rewrite condition:

Comment: I believe that tells apache to not run the rewriete if the file exists.  We just tried both of the rewrite rule methods above without any rewrite condition, but get the same 404 error.  Perhaps this rewrite rule is conflicting with a similar process peformed by/for WP for SEO friendly urls?